# Where to put custom advanced queries in a sailsjs mongodb stack

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, postman, sails-mongo

I want to proceed with more advanced queries in a sailsjs and mongodb stack where sailsjs is setup to serve as an api with data against a front end client. I've been able to fetch data with some basic queries but now looking into on how to proceed with more advanced ones. For example, I want to query the database for entries where the string match either the title or the text, something like this,

`db.mycol.find({$or:[{"text":/.*test.*/},{"title": /.*test.*/}]})`

My question, where do I put this logic? Any hints, links, tutorial that could point me into the right direction for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate an api, for example:
`sails generate api Customer`

Sails will create a CustomerController for you in api>controllers.

You can add whatever custom endpoints you want to that.

If I put in CustomerController

```
blah: function(req, res) {
    res.json(200, 'You are at blah');
}
```

and I navigate to customer/blah, it will hit that endpoint.  So you can add whatever custom endpoints you want to for that controller.  Go crazy.

Do not forget that sails has policy enforcement that you need to set up in the config/policies.js.  This lets you expose, block, or add whatever middleware you need to in order to keep your back end as secure or open as it needs to be.

Comment: Excellent this is what I needed to proceed. Thanks.